# Roles in Azure. Permission to view invoices

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I really need some basic help with Azure.  I purchased Microsoft 365 for my company (10 users) from GoDaddy (a mistake).  GoDaddy support has little to no knowledge of Azure.  With Microsoft 365, you get access to the Azure portal, and you get a directory in Azure Active Directory that looks like NETORG12345678.onmicrosoft.com.   Then you can create tenants and subscriptions below that directory.

I must have done something like that, because now I am getting emails from Microsoft saying that my subscription is about to expire and I should pay the bill.

[image]

Rather embarrassing to say, but I cannot even figure out how to do this.  I am the global administrator for my directory/tenant (if that is even the right terminology).  I keep getting error messages that I don't have the appropriate permissions to view my bill, and I should try asking myself for permission to do that.  Sometimes, the error messages say I should try switching directories, but there is only one directory, I think.

I wish there was some appropriate training for this, but I can't find anything.  Sorry for the noob question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the owner/administrator you can navigate to **`Cost Management + Billing`** and see what is your subscription and the status of it,

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but my screen just doesn't look like your's at all.  I don't even have a Subscriptions item in nav bar.  I am "in" the subscription, and when I say "cancel subscription", it says only the owner can do that, but I am the owner.  Then it asks me to email myself and ask for permission.  This is so confusing.  I would post a screenshot, but I don't know how to do that.  These comments appear to allow only text.

Comment: That's strange. you can take a screenshot and post in your question. How you are saying that you are the owner?

Comment: OK, I added a screenshot to the question.  When I hit the Email account admin button, an Outlook window pops up telling me to send an email to myself.

Comment: I guess you are doing some basics wrong, i am not able to figure out what it is.

Comment: In the same screen can you got to Access control and see what is your role?

Comment: Yes, I have raised a critical issue level A with Microsoft, and they can't figure it out either.

Comment: I would recommend to first, check your role - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-manage-roles-portal#view-my-roles

Then check how many subscriptions are there in your https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/SubscriptionsBlade

Comment: Also in the screenshot, the subscription name says 'Azure Demo' - were you trying to use the free trial?

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that you purchased Office 365 through GoDaddy. In this case GoDaddy could possibly be owning the subscription on which they have on-boarded you. If GoDaddy support doesn't have much idea, you can mention this to Microsoft support. From what I understand you will be paying GoDaddy which would take care of billing on your behalf, I guess.

Comment: My guess is that there are two subscriptions involved here:  First the Microsoft 365 subscription that I paid GoDaddy for, and that GoDaddy manages to give my company the Business Premium services.  And then, there is the Pay-as-you-go subscription that I have created in Azure to host a VM.  I think that is the one that is messed up.